# Can't add image with SonataMediaBundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-media-bundle

I want add to my post images, but i have error. In my logs

> ERROR - Failed to create object: SonataTest\ModelBundle\Entity\Post
>   Context: {"exception":"Object(Sonata\AdminBundle\Exception\ModelManagerException)","previous_exception_message":"An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO Post (title, created_at, updated_at, body, media_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [\"FirstTitle\", \"2015-07-26 11:47:38\", \"2015-07-26 11:47:38\", \"FirstTitle\", 15]:\n\nSQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'sonata.Post' doesn't exist"}

My config.yml

```
doctrine:
.......
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    entity_managers:
        default:
            auto_mapping: true
            mappings:
                ApplicationSonataMediaBundle: ~
                SonataMediaBundle: ~

sonata_media:
 default_context: default
 db_driver: doctrine_orm
 contexts:
    default:
        providers:
            - sonata.media.provider.dailymotion
            - sonata.media.provider.youtube
            - sonata.media.provider.image
            - sonata.media.provider.file

        formats:
            small: { width: 100 , quality: 70}
            big:   { width: 500 , quality: 70}

cdn:
    server:
        path: /uploads/media # http://media.sonata-project.org/

filesystem:
    local:
        directory:  %kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/media
        create:     false
```

My entity

```
 class Post
 {
  ..............
 /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="body", type="text")
 */
private $body;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media", cascade={"all"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="media_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $img;
........
}
```

My controller

```
class PostAdmin extends Admin
{
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('title', 'text', array('label' => 'Post Title'))
        ->add('body')
        ->add('img', 'sonata_media_type', array('provider' => 'sonata.media.provider.image',
            'context'  => 'posts'))
    ;
}
.....
}
```

What i do wrong? In my db i have tables post and media

Answer (score 0):

There might be a case issue with your table name, you haven't added `@ORM\Table(name="")` annotation in your entity and in database may be you have table name `post` (in lower case) but when sonata/doctrine generates query in absence of `@ORM\Table` it uses entity name which is `Post` with capital **`P`** if thats the case you can provide table in your entity

```
/**
 * Post
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="post")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Post {
    //..............
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="body", type="text")
     */
    private $body;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media", cascade={"all"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="media_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $img;
    //........
}
```

[***`21.2.34. @Table`***](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-table)